# Negative lookahead vs Positive lookahead syntax

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Given the following text:

> My name is foo.
>
> My name is bar.

With the goal being to return each line which contains or does not contain a particular substring, both of the following positive and negative regex patterns can be used to return the same result:

Postive lookahead: `^(?=.*bar).*$` returns `My name is bar.`

Negative lookahead:  `^((?!foo).)*$` returns `My name is bar.`

However, why does the negative lookahead need to be nested within multiple sets of parentheses with the qualifier `.` and the quantifier `*` separated by the parentheses whereas in the positive lookahead, they can be adjacent `.*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The negative lookahead need to be nested within multiple sets of parentheses with the qualifier `.` and the quantifier `*`* is called a *tempered greedy token*. You do not have to use it in this scenario.

You can use a normal lookahead anchored at the start instead of the [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
^(?!.*foo).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV7uA0/1)

Here,

- `^` - matches the location at the start of the string
- `(?!.*foo)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there is `foo` somewhere on the line (or string if `DOTALL` mode is on)
- `.*$` - any 0+ characters (but a newline if `DOTALL` mode is off)  up to the end of string/line.

**What to use?**

Tempered greedy token is usually much less efficient. Use the lookahead anchored at the start when you just need to check if a string contains something or not. However, the tempered greedy token might be required in some cases. See [*When to Use this Technique*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information about tempered greedy tokens - I didn't know that's what I was doing.

Comment: Actually, I am rather disappointed at the fact that the famous [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) best answer dwells on this tempered greedy token. It is not the best solution for this task. The bottleneck is the unanchored lookahead that is executed at *every location* in the string, while in my answer, the lookahead is triggered right at the start, is executed just once. And it is enough to see if a string has the word or not.

Comment: Nice ref! That's the very answer that confused me!

Answer (score 1):

## Example

Given the string `text = 'a123b456c'`, and we want to use substring `'123'` as an anchor

```
(?=123) Positive lookahead:    Matches substring '123' as a *forward* anchor 
(?<=123) Positive lookbehind:  Matches substring '123' as a *backward* anchor
(?!123) Negative lookahead:    Substring not matching '123' as a *forward* anchor
(?<!123) Negative lookbehind:  Substring not matching '123' as a *backward* anchor
```

`'123'` is only used as an anchor and not replaced. Too see how this works:

```
import re 

text = 'a123b456c'

re.sub('a(?=123)', '@', text) # outputs '@123b456c' note '123' not replaced
re.sub('(?<=123)b', '@', text) # outputs 'a123@456c' 
re.sub('b(?!123)', '@', text) # outputs 'a123@456c' since '456' not match '123'
re.sub('(?<!123)c', '@', text) # outputs 'a123b456@'
```

Hope this helps